# Adding attribute to HTML element causing attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I have a HTML element with an ID: `containerButtons` for which have a number of `labels` and `div`:

```
<div class="button-grp" id="containerButtons">
    <label>Selector 1</label>
    <label>Selector 2</label>
    <label>Selector 3</label>
    <div class="time-container">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="24" step="1" value="00" id="time-hour" disabled="disabled">
        <span>:</span>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="60" step="1" value="00" id="time-minutes" disabled="disabled">
    </div>
</div>
```

The above is created through a JS function in file, buttons.js.

buttons.js:

```
function ButtonsPanel() {

    var that = this;
    this.buttonsEl = document.createElement('div');

    var baseBtn = d3.select(this.buttonsEl);

    var containerBtns = baseFilter.append('div')
        .classed({'button-grp': true})
        .attr({id:'containerButtons'});


    var tmp = containerBtns.append('div')
        .classed({'time-container': true});

    tmp.append('input')
        .attr({type: 'number', min: '0', max: '24', step:'1', value:'00', id:'time-hour', 'disabled': 'disabled'});

    tmp.append('span')
        .text(':');

    tmp.append('input')
        .attr({type: 'number', min: '0', max: '60', step:'1', value:'00', id:'time-minutes', 'disabled': 'disabled'});

    this.timeInputs = tmp;

    var timeHours = this.timeInputs[0][0].children[0];
    // returns <input type="number" min="0" max="24" step="1" value="00" id="time-hour" disabled="disabled">
    var timeMins = this.timeInputs[0][0].children[2];
    // returns <input type="number" min="0" max="60" step="1" value="00" id="time-minutes" disabled="disabled">

}
```

Within buttons.js, i have a method which is called on load toggleVisability:

```
ButtonsPanel.prototype.toggleVisability = function() {

    var that = this;

    this.visabilityApply('#containerButtons', function(num) {
        if (!num) {
            alert(that.timeInputs[0][0].children[0]);
            that.timeInputs[0][0].children[0].attr({'disabled': true});
        }
        else {
            alert(that.timeInputs[0][0].children[0]);
            that.timeInputs[0][0].children[0].attr({'disabled': null});
        }
    });
};
```

With the above, i get error:

```
TypeError: that.timeInputs[0][0].children[0].attr is not a function
```

Yet, if i apply:

```
that.timeInputs.attr({'disabled': true});
```

The above works fine, however, i want to toggle the disabled attributes on the input fields. I am using jQuery.

Comment: Using jQuery , this code would have looked far better and understandable . I can see you have tagged jQuery as well. Do you wish to use it ?

Comment: please create fiddle for your code base, that will be nice to understand :-)

Comment: @TusharGupta - i am using jquery in the project, although not that much in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attr()` is a jQuery function, and as such, needs to be invoked on a jQuery *context*.

In your case:

```
that.timeInputs[0][0].children[0]
```

Returns a native DOM element that doesn't expose an `attr()` function, thus the error (while `that.timeInputs` is still referencing a jQuery context).

Try this instead:

```
$(that.timeInputs[0][0].children[0]).attr({'disabled': true});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still wish to go with Javascript , you can use `setAttribute()` like

```
that.timeInputs[0][0].children[0].setAttribute("disabled", "true");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brakets `{}` whrap the variable in jquery

```
$(that.timeInputs[0][0].children[0]).attr('disabled': true)
```